# Подключение файлов контроллера через dll

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

1. Создаю проект подключаю в нем mvc через nuget. создаю структуру папок controllers, views. создаю файлы соответствующие.
2. Создаю проект asp net mvc, **как в нем использовать controllers/views из dll созданной в пункте 1** ?

Comment: А разве контроллеры из п.1 не должны быть в *asp.net mvc* проекте? Зачем такое разделение?

Comment: Отдельные библиотеки создаются с целью последующего использования. Вы собираетесь использовать повторно контроллеры ?

Comment: @VadimProkopchukr к чему эти лишние вопросы, не нужно лирики. Здесь вроде задают вопросы для получения ответа на определенные технологии/методы программирования, а не для пояснения зачем это и где используется. Случилась такая ситуация в жизни вот и нужно, но не часто и тем более не везде.
Вы если знаете подобные приемы программирования - пишите не стесняйтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добавить контроллеры из другого проекта подключите dll к основному проекту, затем в настройках маршрутизации в RouteConfig укажите те пространства имен из подключаемой dll, которые вы хотите добавить:

```
...    
using ClassLibrary1.Controllers; // Подключаем Dll

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] {typeof(HomeController).Namespace} // Указываем пространства где лежат контроллеры
            );
        }
    }
}
```

По умолчанию, все представления из Views не попадают в dll, а живут как самостоятельные файлы. Движок основного проекта ищет представления в корневой папке проекта по пути "~/Views". Чтобы заставить его видеть представления из проекта dll, необходимо реализовать свой ViewEngine:

```
    public class MyViewEngine: RazorViewEngine
    {
        public MyViewEngine()
        {
            MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
            {
                "~/bin/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", // Все dll помещаются в директорию bin. Вместе с ними будут загружены и файлы представлений.
                "~/bin/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
            };
            ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
            {
                 "~/bin/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", // если используются Area
                 "~/bin/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
            };
        }
    }
```

Свой движок необходимо подключить:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine()); 
    }
```

Альтернативным решением является компиляция представлений в отдельную dll. Тогда её можно будет подключить к проекту и настроить RazorGenerator для работы с данной dll. Однако в этом случае вы не увидите внесенных правок в представления без полной перекомпиляции проекта.

Рекомендую, однако, держать представления в вашем основном приложении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. То что нужно !